Formatting time elapsed in mins in Excel
I currently have some data for time elapsed in the format of dd:hh:mm:ss and excel is reading that as text, and I would like it to convert these values to display the mins elapsed, for example if I had 01:01:01:00 it would convert to 1501
I have tried using power query to convert these values to the duration function but this only produces an error, how could I go about this in power query? I have a lot of fields with this format and it would be ideal if I could do it like that

In powerquery, assuming it is always DD:HH:MM:SS we convert to DD.HH:MM:SS per format requirements of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/duration-fromtext and then use Duration.TotalMinutes
Add column ... custom column ...
= Duration.TotalMinutes(Duration.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter([Column1],":")&"."&Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1],":")))


You're welcome, though usually the procedure is you toggle the checkmark next to the answer that solved your issue to mark your question as solved

You can use Convert and Mid functions:
Convert function converts from x to y, and in your case can convert from days and hours to minuts.
Mid finds a substring in a string.
So, if your text to convert is at P7 cell:
=CONVERT(MID(P7&" ",1,2),"day","mn")+CONVERT(MID(P7&" ",4,2),"hr","mn")+MID(P7&" ",7,2)
Look that the first mid is for the convertion of days to minutes, the second mid is to convert from hours to minutes and you sum it all up with the minutes that you can find in the 7th char to 8th char.
